# Did I just find an awk bug?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, gnu

Using [test2.txt](https://github.com/spakin/awk/files/1167438/test2.txt)

```
$ cat /tmp/test2.txt | hexdump -C
00000000  47 61 6c 6c 6f 20 63 65  6c 74 69 63 6f 0a 47 65  |Gallo celtico.Ge|
00000010  73 97 20 42 61 6d 62 69  6e 6f 0a                 |s. Bambino.|
```

Here is what happened to `awk`:

```
$ cat /tmp/test2.txt | awk '/\x97/{print}'
Ges Bambino

$ cat /tmp/test2.txt | awk '/[\x7F-\xFF]/{next;}; 1'
Gallo celtico
Ges Bambino
```

I.e., the line `Ges Bambino` line contains a char `\x97`, and `awk` confirms that in the first command. However, `\x97` is in the range of `\x7F-\xFF` so the line should be skipped in the second command, but it wasn't.

This really looks like an `awk` bug to me.
Any comments?

PS. making it more evident:

```
$ cat /tmp/test2.txt | awk '/\x97/{next}; 1'
Gallo celtico

$ cat /tmp/test2.txt | awk '/[\x97]/{next}; 1'
Gallo celtico
Ges Bambino
```

UPDATE:

As @KamilMaciorowski pointed out, it is local related. I.e. the above happens when under

```
$ set | egrep '^LANG|^LC'
LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
```

whereas both

```
cat /tmp/test2.txt | LC_ALL=C awk '/[\x97]/{next}; 1'
cat /tmp/test2.txt | LC_ALL=C awk '/[\x7F-\xFF]/{next;}; 1'
```

are giving correct results.

Still, this is an issue, is it?

Comment: Is it the same when you run `LC_ALL=C awk …`? Also [you don't need `cat` here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat), I think.

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem; it may be related to your locale. What's the output of `set | egrep '^LANG|^LC'`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: A true follower of Unix philosophy would instead praise one for usage of pipes, no?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, indeed, it is locale related. OP updated.

Answer (score 2):

Bytes and characters are only identical in the default `C` (aka `POSIX`) locale, but in all other locales they're different. So if your system uses an UTF-8 locale (e.g. `en_US.UTF-8`) by default, then bracketed "character classes" in gawk regexes are based on *characters*, not individual bytes.

For example, `/[eęė]/` is equivalent to `/[e\xC4\x99\xC4\x97]/` assuming an *.UTF-8 locale; however, it will match the letter `ę` but not `č`, despite both having a `C4` byte. (For some reason, this is different from a plain `/\xC4/` *outside* a character class, which *does* match the literal byte `C4`.)

Anyway, the same applies to ranges inside character classes, and since byte `FF` doesn't make a valid UTF-8 sequence, the regex library might just declare the whole range invalid or something.

gawk has the `-b`, `--characters-as-bytes` option to disable this.